# WordPress : Use the ID instead of the title for the permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, slug

Natively WordPress uses the title to generate the permalink but for reasons of confidentiality, I would like not to display the title in the url (for post and custom post type only, not pages).
I would like to use the `id` for example or a series of numbers and letters.

How to change this when we click on "Edit permalink" or when we create a new post?

EDIT:
I do not want to disable url rewrite in `Settings` → `Permalinks`.

Comment: You can change permalink structure from WP admin -> Settings -> Permalink Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found!
It is possible to add `/%post_id%/` in `Custom structure` field. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the *Settings → Permalinks* screen, you can choose one of the more common [permalink structures](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).
You have to choose the first one (Plain) to have the permalinks with id of the post.

Comment: I do not want to disable url rewrite because I'm using caching and rules in the htaccess.
In addition, for custom post types with this permalink structure, we see the title:
`?my_cpt=the-title-here`